# Python Pygame: Sprite not being drawn

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I have a problem with my sprite "Mob" not being drawn on screen.
I checked if it's been adding to the all_sprites group(that's beeing drawn on screen) and it is and I can't find a proper explanation of why it's not working.
I'm still pretty new to pygame so it would be great if someone could also try to explain why is the code not working the way I want it. Thank you :)

My sprites.py(shortened)

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from random import choice, randrange
vec = pg.math.Vector2
# for movement

class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        image = pg.transform.scale(image, (width // 2, height // 2))
        return image


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    ....



class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
 ....

class Pow(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    ....

class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image_up = game.spritesheet.get_image(566, 510, 122, 139)
        self.image_up.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image_down = game.spritesheet.get_image(568, 1534, 122, 135)
        self.image_up.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_up
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = choice([-100, WIDTH + 100])
        self.vx = randrange(1, 4)
        if self.rect.centerx < WIDTH + 100:
            self.vx *= -1
        self.rect.y = randrange(HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vy = 0
        self.dy = 0.5

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.vy += self.dy
        if self.vy > 3 or self.vy < -3:
            self.dy *= -1
        center = self.rect.center
        # každý z obrázků má trochu jinou velikost = centrum je jinde
        if self.dy < 0:
            self.image = self.image_up
        else:
            self.image = self.image_down
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.rect.y += self.vy
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH + 100 or self.rect.right < -100:
            self.kill()
```

My main.py:

```
import random
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from os import path


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the game window
        self.running = True
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption('My game')
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.font_name = pg.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_dir = path.join(self.dir, 'img')
        with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
            try:
                self.highscore = int(f.read())
            except:
                self.highscore = 0
        self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(path.join(img_dir, SPRITESHEET))
        # import sound file
        self.snd_dir = path.join(self.dir, 'snd')
        #self.jump_sound = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(self.snd_dir, 'jump.bfxrsound'))

    def new(self):
        # to start a new game, reset the pieces
        self.score = 0
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mob_timer = 0
        self.player = Player(self)
        for plat in PLAT_LIST:
            Platform(self, *plat)
        # pg.mixer.music.load(path.join(self.snd.dir, filenamw))
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            #pg.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        # Game Loop - Update
        self.all_sprites.update()

        #spawning mobs
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.mob_timer > 5000 + random.choice([-1000, - 500, 0, 500, 1000]):
            self.mob_timer = now
            Mob(self)
            m = Mob(self)


        # deleting the platforms
        if self.player.rect.top <= HEIGHT / 4:
            self.player.pos.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                if plat.rect.top > HEIGHT:
                    plat.kill()
                    self.score += 10

        # check if player hits a platform - only if falling
        if self.player.vel.y > 0:
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                lowest = hits[0]
                for hit in hits:
                    if hit.rect.bottom > lowest.rect.bottom:
                        lowest = hit
                if lowest.rect.right + 10 > self.player.pos.x > lowest.rect.left - 10:
                    if self.player.pos.y < lowest.rect.centery:
                        self.player.pos.y = lowest.rect.top
                        self.player.vel.y = 0
                        self.player.jumping = False

        # die
        if self.player.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            for sprite in self.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.y -= max(self.player.vel.y, 10)
                if sprite.rect.bottom < 0:
                    sprite.kill()
            if len(self.platforms) == 0:
                self.playing = False

        while len(self.platforms) < 6:
            width = random.randrange(50, 100)
            p = Platform(self, random.randrange(0, WIDTH - width),
                         random.randrange(-75, -30))
            self.platforms.add(p)
            self.all_sprites.add(p)

        pow_hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.powerups, True)
        for pow in pow_hits:
            if pow.type == 'boost':
                #self.boost_sound.play()
                self.player.vel.y = - BOOST_POWER

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump_cut()


    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.draw_text(str(self.score), 20, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, 15)
        pg.display.flip()

    def draw_text(self, text, size, color, x, y):
        font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    def show_start_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        self.draw_text("Jumpy!", 40, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4)
        self.draw_text("arrows to move, space to jump", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.draw_text("Press any key to jump", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4)
        self.draw_text("High score: " + str(self.highscore), 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4 + 40)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.wait_for_key()

    def show_go_screen(self):
        if not self.running:
            return
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        self.draw_text("GAME OVER", 48, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4)
        self.draw_text("Score: " + str(self.score), 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.draw_text("Press a key to play again", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4)
        if self.score > self.highscore:
            self.highscore = self.score
            self.draw_text("NEW HIGH SCORE!!", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 40)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.wait_for_key()

    def wait_for_key(self):
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                    waiting = False


game = Game()
game.show_start_screen()

while game.running:
    game.new()
    game.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not being overdrawn, e.g. another image hides it?

Comment: ... are you sure that the Sprite is in the window and not out of the window?

Comment: What does this line do? `self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs`. Sprite.groups() is a method. `https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.groups`

Answer (score 0):

[`groups`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.groups) is an internal method of the class [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). You must rename the attribute `groups`. Or better yet, remove it, you don't need it at all:

```py
class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, [game.all_sprites, game.mobs])
        # [...]
```